# GXT combobox to search from the keyword form anywhere in a word

Tags: gwt, gxt

I am using a GXT ComboxBox to search results from the store. 
But by default it search the word which STARTS from the keyword entered, 
What i want is to find the words from the store which have the entered keyword any where in that word.

So if i type "M" it only gives me "Maths", but I also want to see "sam" or "lamp"

Any idea how this can be achieved here.

thanks

Comment: This feature was added in GXT 4.0.3.

Comment: thanks ,i dont see it in the latest.. not in their showcase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with GXT v4.0.3 you can use the `QueryMatcher` interface:

```
myComboBox.setQueryMatcher((item, query) -> {
  String value = getPropertyEditor().render(item);
  if (value != null) {
    return value.toLowerCase()
                .contains(query.toLowerCase());
  }
  return false;
});
```

Hope that helps.